# Chaining Eloquent queries in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I cannot figure out what would be the best / D.R.Y way to chain a few model methods. For example, I have a `ProjectRepository` class that I inject in my `ProjectsController`. The `repo` class has a method:

```
public function featured()
{
   return $this->model->featured()->order('order')->get();
}
```

In here, `$this->model` is a `Project` model injected in the `__constructor`, and that `featured()` in the query is just a `scopeFeatured()` set on the model itself.

In some cases, I don't want that `featured` method on my `repo` to return items in order at all, so what I want to achieve is something like:

`public function featured() {};`

`public function ordered() {};`

and then to be able to do something like

`return $this->repo->featured()->ordered()`;

Is it possible to do something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Found this useful post and it is exactly what I needed:

http://culttt.com/2014/03/17/eloquent-tricks-better-repositories/